# alternatives to Twilio for sending whatsapp messages

Tags: python, django, whatsapp

I'm trying to integrate a platform for sending whatsapp messages with `Django`, I've tried with `Twilio` but their customer support is a bit slow. Does anyone have any recommendations based on their experience, about platforms that I can use instead of Twilio?